# How does netstat determine symbolic hostname?

Tags: linux, unix, networking, tcp, netstat

I was trying to understand what the `--numeric`/`-n` flag of netstat does? Manual says the following about `--numeric`/`-n`

> --numeric , -n
>
> Show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host, port or user names.

1. Following is a line of output with "-n" option

   ```
   tcp  0  0 :::8080    :::*   LISTEN      -
   ```
2. Following is the same line as in A but without "-n" option

   ```
   tcp  0  0 *:terabase *:*    LISTEN      -
   ```

port 8080 in my case is associated with solr. I have no idea why it's being listed as terabase. That's why I am wondering how netstat determines symbolic host. It would be helpful if someone can throw light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing *ports* and *hosts* I believe.

The symbolic host is determined by DNS lookup, whereas the port usage is what you'll find in `/etc/services` (why you have teradata for port 8080 I don't know - it's usually `http-alt` - but go have a look)

So, for example with `-n` you could have

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

meaning something is listening on port 5432 on IP 127.0.0.1. Without `-n` it would be

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    *:*                     LISTEN
```

which makes us much wiser, since we can now see it's PostgreSQL on localhost.

The price for that information is that the DNS roundtrips take time...!

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how it looks up "program name"?  is there a file for that too? Also, how is  /etc/services being written and managed? Like do induvidual etc scripts write to it?

Comment: In the `/proc/<PID>` filesystem

Comment: Most of the entries in /etc/services are registered with IANA - the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (RFC 6335). Packages and programs do not generally mess with this file.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you're looking at a port mapping, and not a host mapping.
Port numbers are looked up in the /etc/services file, or some other database configured in /etc/nsswitch.conf

You have an entry /etc/services for terabase, mapping it to a port/protocol.

(terabase would normally be mapped to port 4000, so ether your /etc/services maps it to port 8080, or the line you're looking at is for port 4000 and not port 8080 as you assume).